# Database restore fails in most scenarios

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-restore

I am trying to restore database and it fails with error with 2 /3 options tried

RESTORE DATABASE abcdDb
 FILE = N'abcdDb'

FROM DISK = N'i:\Data\abcdDb.bak'

Fails with Error

Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb.mdf" 
failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
File 'abcdDb' cannot be restored to 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb.mdf'. 
Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb_log.ldf" 
failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
File 'abcdDb_log' cannot be restored to 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb_log.ldf'. 
Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
 
FROM DISK = 'i:\Data\abcdDb.bak'

Gives me output as follows

abcdDb  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb.mdf  D    
abcdDb_log  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb_log.ldf  L
Used above file location to restore as below

IF DB_ID('abcdDb') IS NULL 
BEGIN
  RESTORE DATABASE abcdDb
  FILE = N'abcdDb'
  FROM DISK = N'i:\Data\abcdDb.bak'
  WITH 
    FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10,
    MOVE N'YC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb.mdf'
    TO N'C:\Data\abcdDb.mdf',
    MOVE N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb_log.ldf'
    TO N'C:\Data\abcdDb.LDF'
END

(2 row(s) affected)
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Logical file 'YC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\abcdDb.mdf' is not part of database 'abcdDb'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

Second logical filename is not correct.from restore file list options , please choose those logical named